# Fit the calendar format

Tags: android, calendar, format

I want mask yyyy/mm/dd

so..
I have used this code.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
Calendar today = new GregorianCalendar();
String x = today.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"/"+today.get(Calendar.MONTH)+"/"+today.get(Calendar.DATE);
String a = format.format(x);
system.out.println(a);
```

I using this code But this was exception output.

```
08-14 15:24:36.327: E/AndroidRuntime(10133): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

The exception here is the output.

```
String a = format.format(x);
```

the x output 2014/8/14.
it mask yyyy/m/d

What do I need to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

```
    Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

    // (2) create our date "formatter" (the date format we want)
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");

    // (3) create a new String using the date format we want
    String formatted_date = formatter.format(today);

    // (4) this prints "Formatted Date = "
    System.out.println("Formatted Date = " + formatted_date);
```

hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");

String today = df.format(c.getTime());

system.out.println(today);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Date cDate = new Date();
 String fDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").format(cDate);
```

use this code hope it will help you